# need advice and bug help please! (HTML and JS, maybe PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I'm trying to make an auto complete forum (like the tags below) that works in lime-survey. I'm new to this so please explain everything like i'm 5 :)

My goals are:

1. auto complete to work
2. work with lime-survey
3. have an excel file or maybe a database using PHP/MySQL that anyone can manage by editing. It would only be ONE row. Please point me how to do this. I use a mac :)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div > 
    <input type="text" id="raw_input" width="100" height="30" name="box" onkeyup=show(this)> 
</div> 
<div id="drop_down" style="display:none"> 
    <SELECT id=box size=3 name="box" onclick=show(this)></SELECT> 
</div> 

<script>
    function drop_the_box() { 
       document.getElementById("drop_down").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('box').length = 0;

       if (!randomcharactersblablabla).test(document.getElementById("raw_input").value){
           document.getElementById("drop_down").style.display="block";
           var database = new Array("object_1","item_1","object_2","item_2");

            var string = document.getElementById("raw_input").value;
            for (var s = 0; s < database.length; s+= 1 ) {                      
                var t += 1 
                if (database[s].indexOf(string) != 0) {
                    addItem(string[s],database[s]); 
                    scan(streetArray[s],streetArray[s]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function scan(x,y) { 
        var ghost_tag = document.createElement("ghost");  
        document.getElementById("box").options.add(ghost_tag);  
        ghost_tag.text = x; 
        ghost_tag.value = y; 
    } 

    function show(visable) { 
        document.getElementById("dropdown").value = visable.value;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note these sites [*build libraries of high-quality questions and answers*](http://stackexchange.com/about) which also need to be useful for future visitors. Hence, please ask *one* question per post, and make its title summarize that question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep you data in mysql database. Create php file which will handle queries. Use jquery.ajax() to send queries and retrieve responses from php file.

Use this example

jQuery file

```
$('#search').change(function(){
    var name = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'request.php',
        data: 'some data(may be variable)',
        success: function(response){
            $('#searach').val(response);
        }
    });
})
```

php file

```
if(isset($_POST['some_data'])){
    $query = 'SELECT your_table_field FROM your_table WHERE your_table_field LIKE %$_POST['some_data']% LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $myrow[0];
}
```

Comment: And enjoy the world of sql injection attacks!

Comment: :) Use mysql_real_escape_string()